# How do I test an SVG fallback?

Tags: google-chrome, testing, svg, fallback

Is it possible to turn off SVG support in Chrome to test an SVG fallback? If not, what's the best way to test this on a Mac running El Capitan?

Answer (score 1):

Download [Firefox 1](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/1.0/) that's ancient enough not to support SVG.

In Firefox versions between 1.5 and 3 you can turn off SVG support via about:config - set svg.enabled to false. This configuration setting does not work in newer versions of Firefox though.

Comment: Looks like that's a PowerPC app which won't run on my Mac. [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) says Firefox 2 had partial SVG support, so I can't go any newer.

Comment: I've updated my answer, you can use newer versions of Firefox (up to a point) but you need to set a configuration flag.

Answer (score 0):

[Camino](http://caminobrowser.org) is a decent option for macOS users. It's got the `svg.enabled` option in `about:config` to completely disable its SVG support.